# cocos2dx ios sprite coordinates and size errorneous

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-x

I am using multiple resources to support multiple devices with different resolution. I followed the guidance here:

[Cocos2d-x multi resolution support](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support)

It works well on Android and Windows, but when I run on XCode, all the position are messed up. And to make it even worse, I get different value whenever I rebuilt! It is just like apple is messing up my sprite position by adding rand() value...

I have been debugging for hours and absolutely clueless... Apple products (especially the developer tools) have always been buggy.. I have been searching the internet to no avail... is it just me that encounter this bug? is it some problem with my code? Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you load your Resources into xcode?

Note that you have to add all the multi-resolution folders as "Folder Reference". Adding it as "Group" will not work and you will get bugs where a random asset is chosen

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Mechanism_of_loading_resources